# Sql query in php not returning the value

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am implementing a shopping website for food items. I have a cart for each of my visitor and in the cart, the details of their food items are fed. I have a field called Food_Name in my `cart` table and I have another table called `food` where I have `Food_Name, Food_Id` among other details.

I am trying to retrieve the food id by using `Food_Name` in my `cart` table and performing a query to get the corresponding food id in my `food` table. However, I am not getting any result for my `food` item.
The query however works when I hardcode the value of one of my food name for e.g 'Vegetable Gratin' in the place of `$foodCommand`

Please help me. It's very important

Here is part of the code

```
$retrieveCart="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cartNo='$cartNo'";
$res3=$conn->query($retrieveCart);

while($rowresult=$res3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

    $foodCommand=$rowresult['Food_Name'];

    echo $foodCommand; //I get the correct food name

    $retrievefid = "SELECT Food_Id FROM food WHERE Food_Name='$foodCommand'";
    echo $retrievefid;

    echo "</br>";

    $foodresult = $conn->query($retrievefid);
    $roww= $foodresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $fid = $roww['Food_Id'];
    echo "fid is ".$fid;
    $qty=$rowresult['qty'];
    $fprice=$rowresult['Food_Price'];

    $odetails="INSERT INTO 
                                visitor_order_details(Food_Id,OV_Id,O_Qty,`Price_Paid(Rs)`) 
                        VALUES('$fid','$vid','$qty','$fprice')";

    $conn->exec($odetails);

}//endwhile
```

---

Edit:

I am getting the following error:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\trial2\checkout.php on line 140

Comment: Hi, use multi_query() instead of query() function

Comment: @giovybus They're using PDO, not mysqli_.

Comment: @giovybus what difference does it make?

Comment: Any errors via PDO? https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and error reporting?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ya it did not work

Comment: PDF vs MYSQLI https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-vs-mysqli

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner got this error Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\trial2\checkout.php on line 140

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner getting this error because it is not getting the food id value

Comment: I guess `$roww` is `false` because of some error, so `$roww['Food_Id']` throws an error.

Comment: @RomanHocke i echoed the values. I got $foodCommand correctly and when i hardcode the value of $foodCommand like 'Vegetable Gratin', I get the food id

Comment: Did you check for errors on the query also with the first link I gave? That doesn't check PHP errors, it checks for PDO errors. Also, what do you get when you `var_dump()` the query where you're retrieving from the `food` table?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes i did and i did not get additional errors. How should i use the var_dump()? Is it on the query or the results?

Comment: You use `var_dump($variable)` and replace the variable with the ones associated with the ones you're using for the `food` table query. Have a look also at the duplicate that another member used to close the question. If that still didn't work, then ping that person to see if they can shed some light on that and possibly ask them reopen if it didn't solve your question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I get this string(67) "SELECT Food_Id FROM food WHERE Food_Name='Vegetable Gratin '"

Comment: `WHERE Food_Name='Vegetable Gratin '"` < notice you have a trailing space in there at the end, most likely the reason. Try using `trim()` maybe, or find out why the space. Maybe it was created with `\n` somewhere.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner THANKS A LOT!!! I've been on that for 5 hours! U r a genius :D

Comment: Right on, glad to hear it :D *Cheers!* Funny the little things like that and what they'll do sometimes. Hey.... I've been there too ;-) Take care.

Comment: On a side note, you must use JOIN in your SQL and prepared statements in PDO

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes we know that well :D.. Cheers u too n stay safe! ;)